# How to select cells and merge them?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new to VBA and doing some coding to do produce duplicate table from a form.
But I'm stuck with selecting one part where I need to select a few cells and merge them. After merging, I still need to box them up.
Anyone can help?

```
For Counter = 1 To Me.Copies.Value

RowCount = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
.Offset(RowCount, 0).Value = Me.Location.Value
.Offset(RowCount, 0).Select
Call Macro1
.Offset(RowCount, 1).Value = StEt
.Offset(RowCount, 1).Select
Call Macro1
.Offset(RowCount, 2).Value = Me.Supervisor.Value
.Offset(RowCount, 2).Select
Call Macro1
.Offset(RowCount + 1, 0).Value = Counter
.Offset(RowCount + 1, 0).Select
Call Macro1
.Offset(RowCount + 1, 1).Value = Me.ExactLoc.Value
.Offset(RowCount + 1, 1).Select
Call Macro1
.Offset(RowCount + 1, 2).Value = Me.SupNum.Value
.Offset(RowCount + 1, 2).Select
Call Macro1
.Offset(RowCount + 2, 0).Value = Me.AddMsg.Value
'this is where I need the cell and 2 more other cell together for a merge
End With
Next Counter
```

These codes are based on a button to be click on a form with all the values being filled up in the form.
The code will duplicate the value in the text field to the amount of copies need to be produce.

Comment: Merged cells are pain to work with and can cause a lot of problems. Why not use a different technique?

Comment: How do you plan to select them? If you can create a `Range`-object, you can simply set `.MergeCells = True`

Comment: My probem is I don't know how to select the cells.

Answer (score 0):

To merge cells

```
Range("C16:E17").Merge
```

A couple of things you will come accross is that merged cells are best left alone in Excel especially when it comes to vba as you will get errors when trying to do certain things.

Another thing to bear in mind is that the above code I got from the macro recorder, which can help sometimes.

Comment: I need an answer on how to select the cell rather than how to merge.

Comment: You dont need to select the cell (selecting the cell is actually a very inefficient way of doing things), you can do everything from the range object. In your code you could do something like range(.offset(Rowcount+3,0).address,.offset(Rowcount+4,0).address).merge

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
Range("C16:C17").Select
Selection.Merge
With.Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
.LineStyle=xlContinuous
.Weight=xlMedium
End With
With.Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
.LineStyle=xlContinuous
.Weight=xlMedium
End With
With.Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
.LineStyle=xlContinuous
.Weight=xlMedium
End With
With.Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
.LineStyle=xlContinuous
.Weight=xlMedium
End With
```